# How to count number of inner documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to mongodb concepts

```
   outerob{ 
   _id:111,
   name:xxx,
   dependents : [ {
                  name:a,
                  age:11
                  } 

                  {
                  name:b,
                  age:12
                  }
                  {
                  name:a,
                  age:11
                   }
                  ]
            }
```

I have collection like this. I want to count number of dependents. please help me with this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the number of items in array by using Aggregation framework as follows :

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
    { $unwind: "$dependents" },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
);
```

You can find the number of items with specific name as follows :

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
    { $unwind: "$dependents" },
    { $match : {"dependents.name" : "a"}},
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
);
```

Comment: how can i get cpunt for perticular name ?

Comment: what you mean by cpunt?

Comment: I have updated query to find the count of items with specific name.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 x=db.collection.find({_id:111}).toArray()[0].dependents.length
```